# Fold and map at the same time

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I have a function

```
f : a -> b -> ( a, c )
```

and I need to apply `f` to a list of `b`, while `a` is accumulated and `c` is appended to a list, getting `( a, List c )`. I think the signature of what I want to do is

```
(a -> b -> ( a, c )) -> a -> List b -> ( a, List c )
```

---

The real scenario here is that I have

```
getThing : Model -> Thing -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
```

and need to run `getThing` on a list of `Thing`, passing the `Model` to each call to `getThing` and returning the model and all `Cmd`s that are to be performed in a `Platform.Cmd.batch`.

I think this problem should be broken down into multiple parts, but I am not sure where to start. It feels like using a fold is appropriate for the `Model`, but I need a map for the `Cmd` part.

Comment: In haskell this is known as [`mapAccumL`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:mapAccumL). Not sure whether the same exists in the Elm standard library as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to unpack the tuple returned by `getThing` in each iteration of the fold, then pack it back up with the command added to the accumulated list of commands as the accumulator.

```
mapThings : (a -> b -> ( a, c )) -> a -> List b -> ( a, List c )
mapThings getThing initialModel things =
    List.foldl
        (\thing ( model, cmds ) ->
            let
                ( newModel, cmd ) =
                    getThing model thing
            in
            ( newModel, cmd :: cmds )
        )
        ( initialModel, [] )
        things
```

The naming here is very specific to help mnemonics, but it can easily be generalized just by using more generic variable names.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind pulling in another package, there's elm-community/list-extra List.Extra.mapAccuml and List.Extra.mapAccumr

https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/latest/List-Extra#mapAccuml